Visual Studio 2022 VB and Crystal Report sp35: Trying to create new Crystal report, error: "The system cannot find the file specified"
I am using Visual Studio 2022 VB and I have installed Crystal Report sp35. When I try to create a new Crystal report, I get following error message:

The system cannot find the file specified.(Exception from HRESULT:0x80070002)

Screenshot of the error:


This question is similar to: How to fix the "The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT:0X80070002)" error in Visual Studio?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hey Microcrap, it would be nice to know, which file was specified, don't ya think?
